# Is it possible to compute a file's SHA1 ID using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, sha1

If this were possible to do prior to posting a form, it may save me having to upload the file to my server...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How would I get a Hash value of a users file with Javascript or Flash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539488/how-would-i-get-a-hash-value-of-a-users-file-with-javascript-or-flash)

Comment: It may help.: [How can I hash a string with SHA256 in JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68545495/9935654) support `SHA-1`, `SHA-256`, `SHA-384`, `SHA-512`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do that you would have to load the file's binary information into JavaScript. Which is not possible.

But [here's](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-sha1.html) an implementation of SHA1 in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you **can** read the contents of a client-side file now, as long as it's chosen in a file upload field and you are using Firefox. See the [input.files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NsIDOMFileList) array. You can then indeed hash it, although it might be rather slow.

See [How would I get a Hash value of a users file with Javascript or Flash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539488/how-would-i-get-a-hash-value-of-a-users-file-with-javascript-or-flash/539886#539886) for an example and a compact SHA-1 implementation.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use SHA1, though performance isn't going to be the best...

For anything over a few hundred KB's you will have to run some benchmarks and determine if indeed its a viable solution.

See [this link](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/sha1.html) for a good implementation (passpack and quite a few OS projects use it)

Edit: 
As other have already replied, actually getting the file contents may be a whole different matter - so unless you use something like Google Gears or Adobe AIR it should be virtually impossible.

Answer (score 1):

One can read their local file using the HTML5 File interface:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

And then you can use a library for like Crypto.js https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/ to finish the hash over the read text.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't access a file from a local computer using JavaScript .

You're going to have to upload it first to the server, then checking the checksum of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Not natively, no, and this is a bad idea anyway. Every byte in the file will have to be loaded into memory by Javascript, and you'd need a way to get it there.

If you must do this and you've got a way to put the file's binary information into your script, then [there's plenty](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+sha1+implementation&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=com.ubuntu:en-US:unofficial&client=firefox-a) of third-party scripts you can use. [**Here's one**](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/sha1src.html), for example.

Comment: Second link is broken. Fixed link with sha1: http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/index.html

Comment: @JohnFeminella thx for your comment: would you know how these guys calculating SHAs: https://md5file.com/calculator

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a Java applet.  I've never used any of them, but there are quite a few Java upload applets out there.  The hash algorithm itself is available with Java and can be accessed through java.security.MessageDigest.  If the client doesn't have the Java plug-in available you could just fail back to a regular upload and hash on the server.

A side note: depending upon why you're hashing the file you'll probably want to re-hash it on the server after the upload rather than trust the client.