# Is there any equivalent JavaScript function for PHP`s hash_hmac()?

Tags: javascript, php, amazon-web-services

We are developing an online course website. 
Courses have audio and text (no video). 
Audio files are stored on Amazon S3 and delivered via AWS CloudFront.

Every time a user wants to play a course audio file, 
website (server side) sends a request to CloudFront to get the audio file. 
Each request also includes a signature and a random number.

We use PHP hash_hmac to generate the signature as follows:

```
$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $random_number, $secret, true);
```

Both sides (website and CloudFront function) have the secret key hard-coded.

Once CloudFront receives the request, 
a "CloudFront Function" (new AWS feature) is validating the token. 
CloudFront Function can only use JavaScript (not NodeJS nor Python). 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-cloudfront-functions-run-your-code-at-the-edge-with-low-latency-at-any-scale/

**We want CloudFront function to simply run hash_hmac() using JavaScript 

and then compare the signatures but we could not find an equivalent JS function.**

We checked extensively on StackOverflow but could not find an equivalent JS function. 
Our findings: 
Google`s Crypto-JS library is deprecated. 
NodeJS Crypto module cannot be used since we use plain JavaScript.

**Can someone PLEASE share a link or a code snippet on how to run hash_hmac on JavaScript?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I hash a string with SHA256 in JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59777670/how-can-i-hash-a-string-with-sha256-in-js)

Comment: @biesior I’m not sure this would qualify as “client side” as the script is executed on a CloudFront Edge Location, not in the requesting browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So one way is to use JS crypto.subtle.sign as @Guerric P mentioned above.

It turns out there is another way to achieve it. 
After reading the complete CloudFront developer guide, 
I found the following:

NodeJS has a great module called Crypto.

In general, we cannot add a NodeJS module to JavaScript code.

However, CloudFront Function (who use plain JS only) supports also NodeJS Crypto module: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/functions-javascript-runtime-features.html#writing-functions-javascript-features-builtin-modules-crypto

> The cryptographic module (crypto) provides standard hashing and
> hash-based message authentication code (HMAC) helpers. You can load
> the module using require('crypto'). The module provides the following
> methods that behave exactly as their Node.js counterparts.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a native [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto) for that:

```js
(async function () {
  const someData = 'Very genuine data';

  const key = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey({
    name: "HMAC",
    hash: {
      name: "SHA-256"
    }
  },
      true,
      ["sign", "verify"]);

  let enc = new TextEncoder().encode(someData);

  const signature = await crypto.subtle.sign('HMAC', key, enc);

  console.log(signature); // ArrayBuffer(32)
  
  const valid = await crypto.subtle.verify('HMAC', key, signature, enc);
  
  console.log(valid);
  
})();
```

Comment: Indeed as I read your question again, it makes no sense to use HMAC since the key (supposedly private) is actually made public because included in the frontend