# How to calculate SHA hash of a string in browser JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web, browser, hash

Very new to JavaScript I am.

#### What I think I know

- There's the `CryptoJS` module for the frontend.
- There's a `Closure Library` by Google.

#### I tried

- Using the `CryptoJS` module. But I didn't get the hexadecimal hash.
- Using the closure library according to [this doc](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/gettingstarted), [this example](https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/26f61837b5437ac6e2735bcfb1461baff85c67ed/closure/goog/crypt/sha1.js#L12) and from [this cdn](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/google-closure-library?path=closure%2Fgoog).

### But my question is

- Is there a native crypto library on browser?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a native browser crypto.

A code example for what you want is:

```
const text = 'An obscure body in the S-K System, your majesty. The inhabitants refer to it as the planet Earth.';

async function digestMessage(message) {
  const encoder = new TextEncoder();
  const data = encoder.encode(message);
  const hash = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', data);
  return hash;
}

digestMessage(text)
  .then(digestBuffer => console.log(digestBuffer.byteLength));
```

The above example is found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest) which is a good start for in-browser cryptography.

Comment: example that returns a string instead of array buffer: https://gist.github.com/technikhil314/40f3c41e1039f4c7964843e47a9f25fc

Answer (score 0):

Re : "Is there a native crypto library on browser?"

You may use CDN library.

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/crypto-js

Please quote the following script tag into your html :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js" integrity="sha512-E8QSvWZ0eCLGk4km3hxSsNmGWbLtSCSUcewDQPQWZF6pEU8GlT8a5fF32wOl1i8ftdMhssTrF/OhyGWwonTcXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

For how to use the methods from the library , please refer to the website below :

https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/

The following page shows an example where my suggestion comes from :

https://codepen.io/omararcus/pen/QWwBdmo